# Remove modules with composer

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, module

In my current setup, I don't use all features from Magento 2 and I won't. I already tried to disable the modules that I don't need but disabling just disables the output of the specific module. It does not remove it physically.

To remove modules, I tried to remove them via composer, but each one that I tried ended up in a big mess where nothing was working.

How can I check the dependencies of the Magento modules to wch other? I tried the

```
Composer show --tree
```

Command, but that is not analyzable.

To have a concrete example: how can I find the dependencies of the ups module of Magento?